# How do i select and replace <option>?

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` field.

```
<select name="select-states" disabled="disabled"><option value="">Choose State &raquo;</option></select>
```

I would like to replace just the `<option>` inside the `<select>` with the response received from Ajax Script which contains multiple  elements.

I would like to know the selector for selecting `<option>` which is a child of `<select name = "select-states">` without using the id attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all options

```
$('select[name=select-states] option')
```

to get selected option

```
$('select[name=select-states] option:selected')
```

to replace its options with ajax response

```
$('select[name=select-states]').html(AjaxResponseHtml)
```

Comment: this one will set inner html of selected option element

Comment: $().html() set/retrieves innerHTML but does not replace the element. The code $('select[name=select-states] option').html(AjaxResponseHtml) does not replace the option

Comment: sorry I forget to remove `option` from  the selector, thaks

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select[name=select-states] option');
```

Comment: $('select[name=select-states] option').replaceWith('the received html');

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('select[name="select-states"] option')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the `<option>` element (and anything that's inside the `<select>`), you should use:

```
$('select[name=select-states]').html(ajaxResultHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":select[name='elect-states']").find("option")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('select[name="elect-states"]').empty().append(function() {
    var str = '';

    // construct HTML string from Ajax-response data

    return str;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="select-states"] option').replaceWith(jQueryAjaxWrapper);
```

Where `jQueryAjaxWrapper` is the result of your AJAX call wrapped in jQuery :P